# Add and remove table rows dynamically with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a beginner in jQuery. I have to put add and remove buttons to each table row. When remove any of row, I want the first column values to be serialized in ascending order. Now I just don't get it. Will appreciate for your help.

These are my jQuery codes:

```
$(function(){
        $(".addButton").click(function(){
            var x=document.getElementById('applyList');
            var new_row = x.rows[1].cloneNode(true);
            var len = x.rows.length;
            new_row.cells[0].innerHTML = len;
            var select = new_row.cells[1].getElementsByTagName('select')[0];
            select.id += len;
            select.value = '1';
            var inp1 = new_row.cells[2].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
            inp1.id += len;
            inp1.value = '';
            var inp2 = new_row.cells[3].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
            inp2.id += len;
            inp2.value = '';
            x.appendChild( new_row );
        });

        $(document).on('click', '.deleteButton', function() {
            var x = $('#applyList tr').length;
            if(x == 2){
            } else {
                 $(this).closest("tr").remove();
                 var row = $(this).closest("tr") // get to the row
                 row.children().each(function(){

                 });
            }
        });
    });
```

This is html codes:

```
<table class="list" id="applyList">
                                <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th class="thead color-white width-30">#</th>
                                    <th class="thead color-white width-150">Route</th>
                                    <th class="thead color-white width-50">Fare [MMK]</th>
                                    <th class="thead color-white width-50">Remark</th>
                                    <th class="thead color-white">
                                        <button type="button" id="add" class="button-style tbl-button button-sm bg-color-sky-blue">ADD</button>
                                    </th>
                                </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>1</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <select>
                                            <option value="1">Home->Office->Home</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </td>
                                    <td><input type="text" class="width-50"/></td>
                                    <td><input type="text" /></td>
                                    <td>


                                        <img class="addButton width-30 height-30 align-middle" src="../../public/img/busfare/plus.png"/>
                                        <img class="deleteButton width-30 height-30 align-middle" src="../../public/img/busfare/minus.png"/>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                            </table>
```

The output is here:

[image]

[Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/nwt31t45/)

Comment: If you have 1 to 5 rows and if you will remove #3 then #4 will come up just after #2. Can you explain what you want to achieve?

Comment: can you provide fiddle for a working example.. as ques is not clear.

Comment: Question is not clear please provide the expected result with some screenshots or some example

Comment: Question? I don't even see a question mark.

Comment: Dear all, I added fiddle link. Thank you.

Comment: Only the add button at the first row works. And when remove #1 row, #2 row  should become #1. Thats all I want. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming when the `button#add` adds a row at the end of the table and the `img.addButton` adds a row after that line. Here you have my approach...

```
function createRow(id) {
    var newrow = [
        id,
        '<select><option value="1">Home->Office->Home</option></select>',
        '<input type="text" class="width-50"/>',
        '<input type="text" />',
        '<img class="addButton width-30 height-30 align-middle" src="../../public/img/busfare/plus.png"/><img class="deleteButton width-30 height-30 align-middle" src="../../public/img/busfare/minus.png"/>'
    ];

    return '<tr><td>'+newrow.join('</td><td>')+'</td></tr>';
}

function renumberRows() {
    $('table#applyList tbody tr').each(function(index) {
        $(this).children('td:first').text(index+1);
    });
}

$('button#add').click(function() {
    var lastvalue = 1 + parseInt($('table#applyList tbody').children('tr:last').children('td:first').text());
    $('table#applyList tbody').append(createRow(lastvalue));
});

$('table#applyList').on('click','.addButton',function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').after(createRow(0));
    renumberRows();
}).on('click','.deleteButton',function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    renumberRows();
});
```

I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use `splice()` method to remove element from Array. For detail check https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp